# Automatically expire NSURLCache with max-age=0

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, etag, nsurlcache

I am using `NSURLCache` with `AFNetworking`. Caching works fine but there is no way to check if a response was actually retrieved from cache.
To check if a cached version is available, I use

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:_request];
```

to check for a cached version of my file.

My server is sending the following headers:

```
Cache-Control:public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
ETag:"317a405bf9f69346c1f0438736a3d02e"
```

This should basically make sure that the cached response is stale immediately after download.
However, `cachedResponseForRequest:` still loads the previously cached version on disk, even if it actually is expired.

- Does `NSURLCache` never expire or am I not sending the correct headers, etc?
- Am I missing something else here?

**EDIT**

I have also tried to send

```
Expires: "Mon, 27 May 2013 14:34:50 GMT"
```

header and the response is still returned from the cache, even if it already expired.
I get the feeling that `NSURLCache` is not working correctly...

Answer (score 2):

NSURLCache is used automatically by most of the iOS network APIs (such as NSURLConnection). You just need to instantiate a NSURLCache object and set it using [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:] somewhere before making any network request.

Even if max-age=0 is set, if ETag is provided, NSURLCache has to store the response so that it can send next request with If-None-Match request header set to the previous ETag value. If server replies with 304, it returns the cached response.

So I think cachedResponseForRequest: is returning the cached response regardless of whether it's actually valid or not.

You won't need to get the cache directly. It's all managed transparently by iOS.